# is there a way to display the hito/jin 人 in non-simplified form?

Tags: kanji, classical-japanese, kanji-choice, academic-japanese

[image]is there a way to display the hito/jin 人 in non-simplified form ?

I see kanji IMAGES everywhere on the net. but I'm looking for a
unicode character like the old Chinese Lishu script.
I see it in signs everywhere, I thought I had seen it in text as well.

Comment: is a valid question to ME because no other place on the internet would really be suitable.  vote not down unless you know this is not where to look. =)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be asking for support with a browser functionality, but upon seeing comments on one of the answers, I am more inclined to think it is asking for support on front-end web-development. Either way, perhaps [superuser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) would be a suitable place to ask.

Comment: It was answered. But the question itself I believe was on topic, but the answer proved the problem itself to be of a different nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a matter of fonts, not a matter of simplification. Much like depending on the font being displayed, a Latin alphabet "a" will either appear with or without the hook at the top, the font determines the exact appearance of the character 人. There are fonts that try to preserve handwriting for CJK characters that will display the 人 character in the way you want it to look.

Some of them packaged with Windows are Chinese 仿宋 and 楷书.

Comment: So... If I force javascript to display the font, and the other person viewing the page DOES NOT have it, it will default back to the simplified version...right?

Comment: Yes, you must find a common-enough font (you can provide a list of like 10 fonts to fall back on if the first one is not locable/locate-able).

Comment: If you absolutely need professional 隷書 font on your site, consider web fonts. For example [TypeSquare](http://typesquare.com/) has a free plan which allows you to use 隷書 font for free for a small site (<10K PV/month).